# Unable to select all Check Boxes from a page,giving error in web driver?

Tags: selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

Here i'm getting all checkboxes of a page but unable to select all check boxes when i tried below code its giving error.Here is my code

```
public class AllCheckBoxes {    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DSamsung&sid=tyy,4io&otracker=nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Samsung");

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        try {
            // Option 1
            List<WebElement> CHECKBOXlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));

            // Option 2
            //List<WebElement> CHECKBOXlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[type='checkbox']"));

            System.out.println("Total Check Boxes are avaliable here are: "+CHECKBOXlist.size());

            for (WebElement checkbox : CHECKBOXlist) {
                checkbox.click();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            // Error as: Element is no longer attached to the DOM 
            // For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
        }

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Can anybody guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stale element exception usually occurs when you are trying to interact with a web element from a previous page instance. Perhaps one of these checkboxes you are ticking does something like reload the page, if this is the case, then the remaining checkboxes to click will fail.

**Edit**: Yes this does seem to be the case after visiting the webpage you are trying to use in your code. My suggestion would be to use indexing within an XPath to get the checkboxes one at a time:

```
public class AllCheckBoxes {    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DSamsung&sid=tyy,4io&otracker=nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Samsung");

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        try {
            // Option 1
            List<WebElement> CHECKBOXlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));

            // Option 2
            //List<WebElement> CHECKBOXlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[type='checkbox']"));

            System.out.println("Total Check Boxes are avaliable here are: "+CHECKBOXlist.size());

            // this for loop will account for page loads:
            for (int i = 0; i < CHECKBOXlist.size(); i++) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[" + (i+1) + "]")).click();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            // Error as: Element is no longer attached to the DOM 
            // For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
        }

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

So basically, you're going to have to find the checkboxes individually rather than all at once to account for page reloading.

Comment: there will be no CHECKBOXlist.length and no click(), please execute and post here.

Comment: @khanam I do not have Java installed so I can't execute it. Use `.size()` instead of length. `click()` is a valid command.

Comment: @khanam the brackets may be incorrect, check the `driver.findElement` function closes.

Comment: Ben, i tried but giving error as: Total Check Boxes are avaliable here are: 411
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='checkbox'][2]"}

Comment: Ben, i have copied same code though it giving as Total Check Boxes are avaliable here are: 411
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='checkbox'][2]"}
Command duration or timeout: 172 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Yeah you need the brackets in the XPath for it to be valid: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='checkbox'])[" + (i+1) + "]")).click();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105119/discussion-between-khanam-and-ben-chand).